# Как установить точный маршрут в адресной строке при запуске приложения, используя react-router-dom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Пример: наше приложение запускается, адрес в адресной строке следующий `http://localhost:3000/`

При этом Route выглядит следующим образом

```
<Route exact path='/'>
  <LogIn/>
</Route>
```

В данном случае будет отображаться компонент `LogIn`

Мне необходимо, чтобы при запуске приложения отображался определенный компонент, т.е. при запуске в адресной строке сразу было, скажем `http://localhost:3000/auth/pages`
Как при этом правильно выстроить `path`?

Comment: то есть, чтобы люди заходили на `http://localhost:3000/`, а их перекидывало на `http://localhost:3000/auth/pages`?

Comment: @Август, да, верно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самый простой вариант, на мой взгляд, это использовать редирект. Просто рядом с рутами нужно написать следующую строку:

```
<Redirect from="/" to="/auth/pages"/>
```

Это выполнит редирект из корневого пути `/` в `/auth/pages`. Почитать можно тут: [Redirect](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect)

Comment: подойдет, спасибо

Comment: к сожалению такой рендер будет происходить постоянно, даже если прописывать в адресной строке другие адреса. Можно ли его вызвать 1 раз? Если говорить в целом, мне необходимо чтобы при старте приложения происходил редирект только 1 раз.

Comment: @rgdzv если у Вас есть какой-то признак, по которому вы можете определить, нужно ли делать редирект, то можно поместить внутри рендер метода компоненту `<Redirect />` в условный рендеринг. Ну, типо так: `{isRerender && <Redirect />}`. Еще расположение `Redirect` в структуре рутов имеет вляние. Расположив его внизу - другие руты будут работать, а в случае, если дойдет до редиректа - и совпадет по урлу - произойдет редирект, иначе - нет.

Comment: странно, я расположил редирект в самом низу, еще один рут должен работать, однако, когда я забиваю адрес этого рута, то опять происходит редирект

Comment: @rgdzv может вы забыли у рута указать `exact`. У меня в проекте сейчас внутри `<Switch>` находится множество `<Route exact ... >` а в конце рутов лежит `<Redirect />` и всё работает.

Comment: уже исправил, `exact` в моем случае не нужен, просто обернул роуты в `Switch`

Comment: @rgdzv а у вас не было `<Switch>`? Если нет, то да, он нужен. Я как раз написал в комментарии выше про `Switch`, `Route` и `Redirect` в то время, как вы мне ответ в комментарии писали.

Comment: да, прочитал, спасибо

Comment: еще 1 небольшой вопрос к вам: если проект обернут в `<BrowserRouter>` то у всех рутов должно появляться свойство `history`? В документации не вижу информацию об этом. Или необходимо оборачивать компонент `withRouter`?

Comment: @rgdzv нужно оборачивать в `withRouter` те компоненты, где необходимо `history`.

Comment: спасибо, помогли

Answer (score 2):

```
// В компоненте объявляем  
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useHistory } from 'react-router'

const MyComponent = () => {
const { push } = useHistory()

// И скажем в useEffect()
useEffect(() => {
push('/auth/pages')
}, [])   // [] - означает выполнить 1 раз (нет зависимостей)
```

Comment: неплохой вариант, но нужно обойтись без хуков, компонент классовый

Comment: можно ли вызвать такую строку `props.history.push('/auth/login')` только 1 раз без хука?

Comment: В классовом компоненте можем вызвать так:// в state добавляем boolean переменную; внутри componentDidMount() проверяем нашу переменную, изменяем state делаем вызов push() // только обязательно проверь не вызывает ли такое действие повторный вызов componentDidMount() //